# FOSUserBundle: Setting distinctive roles and authentication URLs based on the roles

Tags: php, symfony

How should I modify security.yml in order to achieve this scenario?

SCENARIO:

- mysitessss.com -> `student`, `lecturer` and `manager` can access
- mysitessss.com/admin -> `lecturer` and `manager` can access
- mysitessss.com/admin/private -> `manager` can access

And Which exact command should I run to create respective users?

- Students: php app/console fos:user:create ?????????
- Teachers: php app/console fos:user:create ?????????
- Managers: php app/console fos:user:create ?????????

I read the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019937/role-hierarchy-with-symfony2) but I got confused!

**routing.yml**

```
home:
    path: /

admin:
    path: /admin

admin_private:
    path: /admin/private
```

**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_STUDENT: ?????????
        ROLE_LECTURER: ????????????
        ROLE_MANAGER: ???????

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ????????? }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ????????? }
        - { path: ^/admin/private, role: ?????????? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `security.yml` would looks like this:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_LECTURER: [ROLE_STUDENT]
        ROLE_MANAGER: [ROLE_LECTURER]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_STUDENT }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_LECTURER }
        - { path: ^/admin/private, role: ROLE_MANAGER }
```

You can create each user and promote roles for them:

```
$ php app/console fos:user:create student
$ php app/console fos:user:promote student ROLE_STUDENT
$ php app/console fos:user:create lecturer
$ php app/console fos:user:promote lecturer ROLE_LECTURER
# ... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll test it tomorrow and let you know.